# Как сделать не проверку на null ошибкой компиляции?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022

По дефолту не проверка на null прилетает в предупреждениях, а как сделать так, чтобы это было ошибкой компиляции ?

Comment: Воспроизведите эту ошибку, нажмите на подчеркивающую строку, слева появится отвертка (меню быстрых действий), жмите туда, там будет пункт либо сразу с ошибкой, либо "Подавление проблем или настройка уровня их серьезности", жмете, выбираете "Настройка серьезности ...", и выбираете там нужный уровень. После этих действий вам студия сама создаст файл `.editorconfig` в проекте, в котором для указанной проблемы задаст соответствующий уровень.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое!